# How do Fourier-Mukai equivalences not contradict reconstruction theorems?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, abelian-varieties, derived-categories

Apparently there is a thing called Fourier-Mukai equivalence in which the derived categories of coherent sheaves of two distinct schemes (e.g. an abelian variety and its dual) can be equivalent. On the other hand there are lots of reconstruction theorems whose gist tend to be that a scheme is determined by its (derived) category of sheaves, e.g. Tannaka dualities and the Gabriel-Rosenberg reconstruction theorem. How do these not contradict each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fourier-Mukai equivalences are derived, they don't preserve the abelian categories of (quasi)coherent sheaves, unless they are given by isomorphisms composed with line bundle twists. So, there is no contradiction with the Gabriel-Rosenberg theorem.

Furthermore, non-trivial Fourier-Mukai equivalences exist only in the case when the canonical class is neither ample, nor anti-ample. So, there is no contradiction with Bondal-Orlov reconstruction theorem either.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've definitely seen reconstructions in the derived setting, e.g. Balmer's reconstruction of reduced Noetherian schemes from the tt-category of perfect complexes and Lurie's Tannakian reconstruction theorem in the language of derived oo-categories.

Comment: Balmer's theorem uses the monoidal structure of the derived category, which is also not preserved by Fourier--Mukai equivalences. I am not sure, but probably the same is true for the Luries theorem.

Comment: But being left adjoint to Hom, isn't the monoidal structure essentially unique? Also I remember learning that Hochschild cohomology is invariant under FM equivalences, but that uses this tensor-Hom structure in a crucial way.

Comment: Tensor product is adjoint to the **inner** $Hom$, which is not an invariant of a category. And as I said before, most derived equivalences do not preserve monoidal structures. Hochschild cohomology is the Yoneda algebra of the identity functor, it does not use the monoidal structure.